# Поиск новых файлов

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Возможно ли используя клиртул найти все новые файлы (не лежащие под VOB'ом)?

Answer (score 1):

в пределах одной папки мы делали так:
c ls | grep -v "@@" | kci
где алиас с - cleartool, kci - алиас для чекина (правда уже не помню какой)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить список всех файлов снимка, не лежащих в системе контроля версий, используют команду **lsprivate**. Для файлов динамической вьюшки нужен минискрипт. Хорошая статья по близкой теме: "[ClearCase: The ten best scripts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html)".